# Can't read attribute value loaded by jQuery with i.e

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer

How do you make i.e. read the value of attribute included to an element by query?
Everything works fine with Safari, Chrome, Firefox.
The value of "type" below returns undefined only with i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//edit post
$(function() 
{
    $("input[value='Edit']").click(function() 
    {
        $("input#password").attr("rel", "edit");
    });
return false;
});
//----end

//delete post
$(function() 
{
    $("input[value='Delete']").click(function() 
    {
        $("input#password").attr("rel", "delete");
    });
return false;
});
//----end
});


$( document ).on( "keypress", ".enter-pw", function(e){
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 13) { 
        var password = $("input#password").val();
        var type = $(this).attr("rel");
        if(password == ""){
            return false
        }
        if(type=="delete"){
        //do stuffs
        }
        if(type=="edit"){
        //do stuffs
        }
return false;
}

});
```

Problem solved guys.
It was caused by the placeholder plugin which activated only with i.e. .

Comment: Did you notice all the strange colors in your code from the missing quotes

Comment: Yeah if this is working in any browser I may be appalled.

Comment: sorry with that lol. i made few mistakes when i was making it simple for posting a question. can you please review it now??

Comment: Could you include a demo (try for example http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use $(this) to get entry_id and $("input#password") to get password ? Can you try to use $("input#password") both time ?